# PHP header to display a php file to another php file

Tags: php, http-headers

Is it possible to display the content of a php file to another php file?
I have here an example where in the PDF is displayed in a php file.

```
  <?php
    $file = 'path of your PDF file';
    $filename = 'custom pdf file name'; /* Note: Always use .pdf at the end. */

    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    @readfile($file);
    ?>
```

but when I tried to display a php file to another php file. Its not working.

```
<?php
    $file = 'path to my php file';
    $filename = 'custom pphp file name'; 

    header('Content-type: text/html');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    @readfile($file);
    ?>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One way is: `include ('file.php');` if that's the intent

Comment: Hey fred !!! . Yes you are right i guess. I am assuming that OP just want to print the contents of PHP.

Comment: Are you trying to display the code itself, or the processed result?

Comment: Hey Shankar! Probably right. There are quite a few ways doing this lol

Comment: The php file I want to display has the codes for PDF being generated when called. So basically for I just want to change the original.php to new.php

Comment: @user2901740 You're going to need to be clearer in what you want to achieve. There are many ways to include/show content, we need to know **"HOW"** you want it to be displayed and for which purpose. It's a vague request/question.

Comment: it's like this, I have a <form action=original.php"> that will pass all the data to original.php, then original.php will display all the data, I want to change the original.php to new.php, this new.php will have all the content of the original.php. I hope I explained it well thx for your help anyway

Comment: @user2901740 Then what you need is to pass your input variables over. I.e.: form input `<input type="text" name="variable_1">` then in your handler `$variable_1=$_POST['variable_1'];` then you can use that variable anywhere after that and using sessions would also help. However if it's just a simple `file include` I can post an answer. Which in turn will echo a file.

Comment: I tested the file include, I found out that it loads the content of a file you declare i.e include 'yourfile.php',. the problem now is how to get the values that was pass from the form.

Comment: @user2901740 See my edit, I thought that's what you were looking for as well. Reload my answer, there's an example in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to display the contents of another `.php` file:

### show_included_file.php

```
<?php
include ('file1.php');
?>
```

### file1.php

```
<?php
echo "This is the included file.";
?>
```

when upon entering `show_included_file.php` in your web browser,
will echo **This is the included file** if that is the intented result.

### From a form input

Another way of showing content taken from a form (POST method) variable is this:

From a form input, for example `<input type="text" name="variable_1">`

Now if the user enters `Hello world` in the field,

then in your handler `$variable_1 = $_POST['variable_1'];`

you could then do `echo $variable_1;` and it would echo `Hello world`

**PHP handler**

```
<?php
$variable_1 = $_POST['variable_1'];`
echo $variable_1;
?>
```

Comment: Yea fred, that is what OP is looking for +1 !

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Thanks Shankar, much appreciated mate, cheers ;-) (let's cross our fingers lol)

Comment: I tested your answer, 
but I'm getting these errors
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'educontent/wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/templates/tcpdf/samp/flashcards.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\educontent\wp-content\plugins\wordwork\display.php on line 12

I simply add a php file name display.php and declared these codes
include ('educontent/wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/templates/tcpdf/samp/flashcards.php'); The file path is correct, but still getting errors

Comment: @user2901740 it's obviously a path issue. `include()` is a world/global function. Try using the actual (full) path to the file.

Comment: @user2901740 Check these links http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/wordpress-include-template-files.html and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49675/include-php-file-in-content-using-shortcode and http://blogs.shephertz.com/2013/08/27/how-to-include-php-file-to-wordpress/ --- am not a "Wordpress" guy to tell you the truth.

Comment: @user2901740 also try using `<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/filename.php'); ?>` --- `filename.php` being your filename. That's the best I can come up with to try and help you further.

Comment: include ('educontent/wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/templates/tcpdf/samp/flashcards.p‌​hp')
This is the actual path to the file. still getting errors.. hmm .. 
this is my codes,. if (isset($_POST['view'])){
include 'wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/templates/target.php';
}

Comment: @user2901740 Try `if (isset($_POST['view'])){ include TEMPLATEPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/templates/target.php'; }` or `if (isset($_POST['view'])){ include TEMPLATEPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/templates/target.php'; }`

Comment: @user2901740 which actual filename are you trying to include? is it `flashcards.php` or `target.php`?

Comment: Hi I fixed it 
Here's what I did
define (DOC_ROOT_PATH, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
//echo "A $color $fruit"; // A
if (isset($_POST['view'])){

 include DOC_ROOT_PATH."educontent/wp-content/plugins/wordwork/admin/templates/target.php";

}

thx for the help anyway :)

Comment: @user2901740 That's great news am really glad to hear it! You're very much welcome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
<?php
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents("yourphpfile.php"));
```

Comment: As you mentioned, `but when I tried to display a php file to another php file` . this code displays what content you have in your PHP file.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran OP's question is vague, that's the reason I didn't put in an "answer" ;-)

Comment: Your codes displays the codes of the php file, not the output

Comment: Check fredi's answer. That suits your scenario.